# Algorithm to align arrays

Tags: c#, algorithm

Given 2 arrays of double of the same length (The 'Master' array 'A' and secondary 'B'). I want to write a function that 'align' B to A.

I defined alignment such that for each element of A, if B contains that element, then the element should be placed at the same index as A's.

Some specificity on A and B :

- A and B are both initially sorted. After the alignment, B DON'T needs to be sorted.
- A and B are of the same length.
- There is no duplicate neither in A nor in B
- A and B are rather small (10 elements max, more usually around 3-5 elements).
- A should not change.
- I tagged the question C# because it will be my final implementation, but I can adapt the answers
- The function will be called often (100k/1M per seconds), I need something efficient ideally.

Ex1 :

A = [10, 11, 12, 13]

B = [10, 12, 14, 16] (initial)

  = > [10, 16, 12, 14] B Final ([10, 14, 12, 16] is also valid, only the placement of the elements '10' and '12' are relevant (the other elements are not in A))

Ex2:

A = [10, 11, 12, 13]

B = [08, 09, 10, 11] (initial)

 = > [10, 11, 08, 09] B Final

I write two different ways of doing this: one with a dictionary to keep the place of the existing elements, a second one with two pointers that advance in tandem. However, I found the code rather complicated/messy for what it is supposed to do.

Does someone know an existing algorithm for this or a clean and efficient way to do it?

Comment: In your first example, why is B's last 3 number placement changed from 12,14,16 to 16,12,14 ?

Comment: Why did 12 and 16 change places in Ex1?

Comment: @auburg and Wyck it is in order to place '12' at index 3 since '12' is at index 3 in A (place of  the elements '14' and '16' does not matter)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.  Not optimal, but the code isn't bad.

```
private static double[] align(double[] A, double[] B)
{
    var extras = B.Where(b => !A.Contains(b)).ToArray();
    int i = 0;
    var result = A.Select(a => B.Contains(a) ? a : extras[i++]).ToArray();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The 'where/contains' implie an n*n complexity that I don't really like even with (most of the time) a small number of items. The code is clean thought, if I don't find better I will give it a try and see the performance exactly.